# Translate Haskell parsec to FParsec

Tags: haskell, f#, parsec, fparsec

how to translate this Haskell code:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec((<|>), unexpected, lookAhead, noneOf, char)
import Control.Monad(when)

data BracketElement = BEChar Char | BEChars String | BEColl String | BEEquiv String | BEClass String

p_set_elem_char = do 
  c <- noneOf "]"
  when (c == '-') $ do
    atEnd <- (lookAhead (char ']') >> return True) <|> (return False)
    when (not atEnd) (unexpected "A dash is in the wrong place in a bracket")
  return (BEChar c)
```

to FParsec ? Preferable way is without monadic syntax to provide good performance.

Thanks in advance, Alexander.

Sorry for little misleading. I slightly corrected problem to make Haskell code compilable:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec((<|>), (<?>), unexpected, lookAhead, noneOf, char)
import Control.Monad(when)
import Data.Functor.Identity
import qualified Text.Parsec.Prim as PR

-- | BracketElement is internal to this module
data BracketElement = BEChar Char | BEChars String | BEColl String | BEEquiv String | BEClass String
                    deriving Show

p_set_elem_char :: PR.ParsecT [Char] u Identity BracketElement  
p_set_elem_char = do 
  c <- noneOf "]"
  when (c == '-') $ do
    atEnd <- (lookAhead (char ']') >> return True) <|> (return False)
    when (not atEnd) (unexpected "A dash is in the wrong place in a bracket")
  return (BEChar c)
```

Now it is possible to reproduce *p_set_elem_char* computation.

I sincerely thank all of which who helped me.

I made my own approximation, but unfortunately not so functional as it could be:

```
type BracketElement = BEChar of char 
                    | BEChars of string 
                    | BEColl of string 
                    | BEEquiv of string 
                    | BEClass of string

let p_set_elem_char : Parser<BracketElement, _> = 
    fun stream ->
        let stateTag = stream.StateTag
        let reply = (noneOf "]") stream
        let chr = reply.Result
        let mutable reply2 = Reply(BEChar chr)
        if reply.Status = Error && stateTag = stream.StateTag then
            reply2.Status <- Error
            reply2.Error <-  reply.Error
        else if chr = '-' && stream.Peek() <> ']' then
            reply2.Status <- Error
            reply2.Error <- messageError ("A dash is in the wrong place in a bracket")
        reply2
```

Comment: Have you at least tried to do this yourself?

Comment: Please do try, and please supply us with your proposed code and explain why it doesn't match your expectations.

Comment: Yes, but I'm a newbie, so I got some scribbles. And I read FParsec's sources like a dog: understand completely all but can't said nothing. A gap between active and passive lexicon :)

Comment: oh my.. that looks like it will run fast. Just a note - if speed is that important to you, why bother with FParsec? Manually written parser will give you the top speed.

Comment: Your code looks fine, but you shouldn't have to use the low-level API for something so trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `BracketElement` type in toyvo's answer, you could do something like

```ml
let pBEChar : Parser<_, unit> = 
  let c = 
    pchar '-' .>> followedByL (pchar ']') "A dash is in the wrong place in a bracket"
    <|> noneOf "-]"
  c |>> BEChar
```

Comment: Thank you indeed, but your computation is slightly different from the original problem. To test it you can compare run pBEChar "-]";; and  PR.parseTest p_set_elem_char "-]" (I made original code compilable).

Comment: Oops...I misread. You want `followedByL` instead. Code is corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much FParsec, but here is a naive attempt, corrected a bit for performance based on the comments:

```ml
type BracketElement =
    | BEChar of char
    | BEChars of string
    | BEColl of string
    | BEEquiv of string
    | BEClass of string

let parseBEChar : Parser<BracketElement,unit> =
    let okChars = noneOf "]"
    let endTest =
        (lookAhead (skipChar ']') >>. parse.Return(true))
        <|> parse.Return(false)
    let failure = fail "A dash is in the wrong place in a bracket"
    parse {
        let! c = okChars
        if c = '-' then
            let! atEnd = endTest
            if not atEnd then
                return! failure
            else
                return BEChar c
        else
            return BEChar c
    }
```

Comment: It may be worth noting: the monadic syntax is no longer recommended, particularly when performance is a concern (http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/where-is-the-monad.html).

Comment: @Daniel, certainly, but the parser algorithm here is dynamic, how do you work around that? There's going to be at least one `>>=` anyway, as you can't write this in terms of `Applicative` operators. Unless there's some sort of `ifThenElse` in `FParsec`?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what Daniel proposed, you could write that parser as

```
let pSetElementChar : Parser<_,unit> = 
    satisfy (function '-' | ']' -> false | _ -> true)
    <|> (pchar '-' .>> followedByString "]")
    |>> BEChar
```

If you want to add your custom message to the error, you could use `followedByL` like in Daniel's answer or you could add the message using the `fail` primitive

```
let pSetElementChar2 : Parser<_,unit> = 
  satisfy (function '-' | ']' -> false | _ -> true)
  <|> (pchar '-' .>> (followedByString "]" 
                      <|> fail "A dash is in the wrong place in a bracket"))
  |>> BEChar
```

A low-level implementation can be as simple as

```
let pSetElementChar3 : Parser<_,unit> =
  fun stream ->
    let c = stream.ReadCharOrNewline()
    if c <> EOS then
      if c <> '-' || stream.Peek() = ']' then Reply(BEChar c)
      else Reply(Error, messageError "A dash is in the wrong place in a bracket")
    else
      Reply(Error, unexpected "end of input")
```